# Identify and count repeated elements in a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, duplicates

I want to create a function such that, given a vector `V`, it outputs a matrix with columns: the first containing all those elements who are repeated in the vector; and the second specifying how many times that repeated value appears (if it is repeated only once, it should say 2, and so on.).

I've come up with the following code, which can correctly identify the repeated values in the vector, but I don't know how to add the second part: specify how many times that value appears.

```
Repetidos <- function(V){
  Resultado <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
  n <- 0
  for(i in 1:(length(V) - 1)){
    for(j in (i + 1):length(V)){
      if(V[i] == V[j]){
        n <- n + 1
        Resultado[n, 1] <- V[i]
        Resultado[n, 2] <- n
      }
    }
  }
  return(Resultado)
}

V <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5)
Repetidos(V)

> Repetidos(V)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    2
 [3,]    3    3
 [4,]    5    4
 [5,]   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA
```

Comment: Do you accept other methods without loops?

Comment: Sure! Better than nothing. Really appreciate it if you take the time. But eventually I will need something with loops though. Anyway, your way may help getting me unstucked :)

Comment: Try `as.data.frame((tab <- table(V))[tab > 1])`

Comment: Well, that worked perfectly... Could you explain what is it that it is doing?

Comment: `table` is a function that returns the count of each element in a vector. `[tab > 1]` extracts those counts which are greater than 1.

Comment: But why "tab"? Where does it come from? Maybe you could do it in 2 lines of code for me? I don't understand if you're assigning "tab" to be ```table(V)``` or what. Thanks!

Comment: 1: `tab <- table(V)` 2: `as.data.frame(tab[tab > 1])` Assemble them to a one-liner: `as.data.frame((tab <- table(V))[tab > 1])`